# Groovy Multiline String Doesn't Recognize Lines with Only Whitespaces

Tags: groovy

I'm guessing this is a well known issue and there's an efficient workaround somehow.

I am getting output which has lines in it that contain a fixed number of empty spaces. I'm doing a string comparison test such as the one below as part of a unit test. Is there a way to get this to pass without modifying the strings using stripIndent() or the like?

Note, the test below is supposed to have 4 white spaces in the seemingly empty line between testStart and testEnd in the multiline string. However, stack overflow may be removing it?

```
String singleLine = 'testStart\n    \ntestEnd'

String multiLine =
'''
testStart

testEnd
'''

println singleLine
println multiLine
assert singleLine == multiLine
```

Comment: I think I may have found the issue.  I believe intelliJ is removing all the whitespaces from the empty lines in my source code after a few seconds.  I added the four spaces, and ran the test and it passed.  Then, a few seconds later, I saw my cursor jump left and now the tab and spaces are gone.  I will now look at the intelliJ docs for mention of this "feature".

Comment: Even if you disable the stripping of trailing spaces form your IDE, you still have another problem with newline characters in `multiLine` that are not in `singleLine`.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String singleLine = 'testStart\n    \ntestEnd'

String multiLine =
'''
testStart
(assume there are 4 spaces on this line)
testEnd
'''

println singleLine
println multiLine
assert singleLine == multiLine
```

That assertion is supposed to fail.  The first character in `singleLine` is the character `t` from `testStart`.  The first character in `multiLine` is a newline character because the String begins immediately after the opening `'''` and the first character you have after that is a newline character.  You have the same issue at the end of the string.  You could solve that in a couple of ways:

```
String multiLine =
'''\
testStart
(assume there are 4 spaces on this line)
testEnd\
'''
```

Or:

```
String multiLine =
'''testStart
(assume there are 4 spaces on this line)
testEnd'''
```

Comment: My example was flawed and this is the correct answer.  My original issue with my real class was caused by an intellij issue autoremoving. Thanks Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

This was being caused by an intelliJ default setting. I have now resolved it.

http://blog.darrenscott.com/2015/01/24/intellij-idea-14-how-to-stop-stripping-of-trailing-spaces/